# Equivalent Impedance

Tags: impedance, parallel, series

I am unsure if I am approaching this problem in the most efficient and effective way. What changes can I make to my process of finding A and B? My next step was to turn into phase form so that I could divide but I cannot take the inverse tangent of a letter.[image]

Comment: It needs to resonate. Is that in your thinking?

Comment: I just used the equation for impedances in parallel. What do you mean it has to resonate?

Comment: The circuit on the right is to appear as a pure 10 ohm resistor, correct? that requires some Xc and Xl cancellation, in partnership with the 1ohm resistor. With (partial) cancellation occurring near resonance, you may have some ideas on what vector relationships to examine.

Comment: I'm sorry  but I have no clue what you are talking about. How do I know which is the capacitor and which is the inductor?

Comment: Only two choices. Try both. Experiment. You have two values to compute: L and C. And you have two constraints: the frequency and the phase.

Comment: @Hector I follow your logic. It's just \$10\:\Omega=j\,B\mid\mid\left(jA+1\:\Omega\right)\$, as you already wrote. I think your equation is fine. I, instead, would have just followed through with \$10\:\Omega=\frac{-A\,B+jB}{1+j\left(A+B\right)}\:\Omega\$. But the essence is the same. Where are you actually stuck? It looks like you went just so far and simply stopped moving forward. What's stopping you from taking the next step?

Comment: Does multiplying by the complex conjugate mean anything to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are very close. You'd done well up to the point where you just stopped. And I've waited long enough. I'm now going to assume that you either (1) aren't very familiar with complex fractions and don't understand how to use the value "1" composed of the complex conjugate of the denominator to normalize the expression into real and imaginary terms; or else, (2) you do know how, but you don't know why you'd bother with normalizing the expression into real and imaginary terms.

To put a fraction with complex expressions in the numerator and denominator, multiply it by another fraction formed by an identical numerator and denominator made up of the complex conjugate of the denominator. I'll use my own expression, which is the inversion of yours:

$$\begin{align*}
10\:\Omega &=\frac{-A\,B+j\,B}{1+j\left(A+B\right)}\\\\
&=\frac{-A\,B+j\,B}{1+j\left(A+B\right)}\cdot\frac{1-j\left(A+B\right)}{1-j\left(A+B\right)}\\\\
&=\frac{B^2+j\,B+j\,A^2\,B+j\,A\,B^2}{1+\left(A+B\right)^2}\\\\
&=\frac{B^2}{1+\left(A+B\right)^2}+j\,\frac{B\left(A^2+A\,B+1\right)}{1+\left(A+B\right)^2}
\end{align*}$$

But, this has to mean that \$10\:\Omega=\frac{B^2}{1+\left(A+B\right)^2}\:\Omega\$ and also that \$j\,0\:\Omega=j\,\frac{B\left(A^2+A\,B+1\right)}{1+\left(A+B\right)^2}\:\Omega\$. This provides you with two equations and two unknowns. You should be able to solve those for the values of \$A\$ and \$B\$.

Comment: Thanks @jonk, I was actually able to figure it out already. I had to multiply by the complex conjugate to get rid of the imaginary number in the denominator.

Comment: @Hector Great! I'm really glad to hear it. I just couldn't tell and figured I'd just push things along a bit. But it's great to know you got there on your own!! Best wishes.